# XRegExp how to validate a string like Vietnamese name

Tags: javascript, validation, unicode-string, xregexp

Im using XRegExp to validate a string like : Nguyễn , Trần .... (Vietnamese name)

This is my code :

```
var unicodeWord = XRegExp('^\\p{L}+$');
var check =  unicodeWord.test("Trần");
```

but always return TRUE

Someone can help me ? Thanks

Comment: Don't validate names. A name can be anything. Some countries allow people to be named Drag0n the Nguên etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment

Comment: Mean i want allow input only normal character
ex : if user type "Nguyễn" will get error message. They must type "Nguyen" instead of "Nguyễn"

Comment: So you want to check if it validates as alpha? 
 var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/;
Should to the trick. a-zA-Z means match all letters in uppercase and lowercase, that are alphabetic.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I validated correctly written Vietnamese names:-

```
  var firstLetter="[A-EGHIK-VXYÂĐỔÔÚỨ]".normalize("NFC"),
  otherLetters="[a-eghik-vxyàáâãèéêìíòóôõùúýỳỹỷỵựửữừứưụủũợởỡờớơộổỗồốọỏịỉĩệểễềếẹẻẽặẳẵằắăậẩẫầấạảđ₫]".normalize("NFC"),
  regexString="^"
             +firstLetter+otherLetters+"+\\s"
             +"("+firstLetter+otherLetters+"+\\s)*"
             +firstLetter+otherLetters+"+$",
  regexPattern=RegExp(regexString);
```

My full code is at [jsfiddle.net/coas/4djhso1y](https://jsfiddle.net/coas/4djhso1y)